# kivy no python 3.6

Tags: python, python-kivy

Estou usando Python 3.6.2 e estou aprendendo o `kivy`. O *script* não roda porque falta o `sdl2`. 
Já instalei o `pillow` e o `pillow-PIL`, mas não consigo instalar o `sdl2`. Tentei o `pysdl2` e não funcionou.

Script que estou tentando executar:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button()

Test().run()
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Paulo\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-15_39.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Bem complicado executar no Windows, sempre que tentei acabei deixando de lado e voltando para o linux, ainda mais que se você estiver pensando em utilizar o buildozer para gerar um apk, o problema é ainda maior, uma vez que por ser python > 3 o buildozer precisa de um pacote crystax-ndk-... para funcionar. Eu recomendaria linux com uma venv python 2.7, para termos de facilidade ubuntu based distro.

Answer (score -1):

Tente instalar o pacote completo do Kivy:

**Kivy 64 bits:**

https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/Kivy-1.10.1.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

**ou Kivy 32 bits:**

https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/Kivy-1.10.1.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

> Verifique qual a versão do seu sistema operacional para isso.

Instale utilizando o pip:

```
pip install https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/Kivy-1.10.1.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```